# Number of points on schemes modulo $p^k$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be a finite type scheme over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$. Assume that $X_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$ is smooth of dimension $n$, but not necessarily irreducible. Then is
$$X(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}) = O(p^{kn})$$
as $k \to \infty?$

Comment: What if $X$ has a large component living only in the special fibre?

Comment: Good question. In this case clearly $X(\mathbb{F}_p)$ can be very large. But I'm hoping that this problem "disappears" as $k \to \infty$. I looked at a few examples where this happens.

Comment: Indeed. For such a component $Y$, we have $p^n\mathscr{O}_Y=0$ for some $n$, and then $Y(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})=\emptyset$ for $k>n$.

Comment: Oh right, it's $\mathbf Z/p^k$-points, not $\mathbf F_{p^k}$-points. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true, for elementary reasons (i.e. not to do with the Igusa zeta function or something).

By passing to an open cover, we may assume $X$ is affine, say $X = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z_p[x_1,\dots, x_N]/ (f_1,\dots, f_m)$. The Jacobian of this system of equations is an $N \times m$ matrix.

Consider for each $x \in X(\mathbb Z/p^k)$ the minimum $p$-adic valuation of the determinant of an $N-n \times N-n$ submatrix of this Jacobian, considering the $p$-adic valuation of $0$ in $\mathbb Z/p^k$ to be $k$. I claim this is bounded by some constant $c$. If not, we can choose a sequence where this increases to $\infty$ (necessarily with increasing $k$) and then a subsequence which converges $p$-adically, which must converge to a singular point of $X$.

So we may assume that one of these determinants has $p$-adic valuation at most $c$. Summing over the finitely many possible choices, it suffices to bound the number of points assuming a particular determinant divides $p^c$. We may as well throw away all the equations not involved in our fixed submatrix. We will show that, setting all variables not involved in this submatrix to specific values, the number of solutions is $O(1)$. This suffices as the number of ways to assign the other variables is $p^{kn}$.

To do this, consider two solutions $x_1,\dots, x_{N-n}$ and $y_1,\dots, y_{N-n}$. Let $\ell$ be the minimum $p$-adic valuation of $x_j-y_j$. We have $f_i (x_1,\dots, x_{N-n}) = 0= f_i (y_1,\dots, y_{N-n}) = f_{i} (x_1,\dots, x_{N-n}) + \sum_j \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} (y_j-x_j) + O \max_j ( y_j -x_j )^2$. Since the determinant divides $p^c$, for some $i$ the middle term divides $p^{\ell+c}$. So we must either have $\ell +c \geq k$ or we have the middle term cancelled by the following term, meaning $\ell +c \geq 2\ell$, i.e. $\ell \leq c$. So $\ell$ is either in $[0,c]$ or in $[k-c k]$.

This means that, if $x_1,\dots, x_{N-n}$ and $y_1, \dots, y_{N-n}$ are congruent modulo $p^{c+1}$, they are congruent modulo $p^{k-c}$. So the number of solutions in each congruence class modulo $p^{c+1}$ is at most $p^{(N-n)c}$, and thus the total number of solutions is at most $p^{2 (N-n)c}$. This is $O(1)$, and we're done.

Comment: Naturally I'm sure your answer is correct but I'm struggling to follow the precise details of your answer. I'm guessing now this should be well known; maybe there is a reference to somewhere in the Igusa zeta function literature, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: @DanielLoughran Would it be easier to explain your points of confusion and ask me to add details as appropriate than to search through the literature?

Comment: I think I just need to find some time to study it in detail. In the meantime I will leave the question open in case someone knows of a reference to the literature (since I need this for a paper). Thanks!